# Getting different source code for same url

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I'm trying to grab the headline from a Washington Post news page on the web with a simple Perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Web::Scraper;

my $url = 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/why-trump-is-flirting-with-abandoning-fox-news-for-one-america/2019/10/11/785fa156-eba4-11e9-85c0-85a098e47b37_story.html';
my  $scraper = scraper{
        process '//h1[@data-qa="headline"]', 'headline' => 'TEXT',
      };


my $html = get($url);
print $html;
my $res = $scraper->scrape ($html);
```

The problem I'm having is that it works only about 1/2 of the time even when fetching the exact same URL. The source code that is returned is in a completely different format than other times.

Perhaps this is an anti-scraping measure for unknown agents? I'm not sure but it seems like it should never work at all if that was the case.

Is there a simple workaround I might employ like accepting cookies?

Comment: Not much help with the question, but Mojo::UserAgent+Mojo::DOM is a really cool tool for this and you can even do it with [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo): `perl -Mojo -E 'say g(shift)->dom->at('h1[data-qa="headline"]')->text' 'https://example.com'`

Comment: After examining the headers, it looks to me like WaPo has a round robin server set up and one server serves out totally different HTML. Probably some kind of A/B testing or something.

Answer (score 0):

Modified `$scraper` to the following to get it to work with the different source code:

```
my $scraper = scraper {
        process '//h1[@data-qa="headline"]', 'headline' => 'TEXT',
        process '//h1[@itemprop="headline"]', 'headline2' => 'TEXT',
};
```

Either `headline` or `headline` will be populated.